# How to decrease the Advertising Interval of a PiBeacon?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi2

I'm running a Raspberry Pi as a Bluetooth Beacon using the iBeacon Protocol and Bluez stack.
I cannot find any instruction as how to decrease the advertising interval of the Beacons.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advertising interval can be set with the following command:

```
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0006 A0 00 A0 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 00
```

The first four bytes define the min (the first A0 00) and max (the other A0 00) advertising interval.

Read https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=229737 pages 812-813.

To set the advertising interval to 10 packets per second do:

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 up
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008 1e 02 01 1a 1a ff 4c 00 02 15 e2 c5 6d b5 df fb 48 d2 b0 60 d0 f5 a7 10 96 e0 00 00 00 00 c5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0006 A0 00 A0 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 00
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x000a 01
```

Note: that depending on your equipment you might not always achieve the desired effects.